# Error: Invalid hook call. | Problem to fetch data using context inside of getStaticProps (Next.js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm new to react/next and I'm trying to load my post with getStaticProps, the problem is if I use the "useAppContext" or even "useContext(AppContext)"

> error - Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of
> the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the
> following reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

If I use this "useContext" inside of the body of my function component it indeed loads correctly but how could I retrieve the id of the post on my getStaticProps function?

My actual code:

```
import { GetStaticPaths, GetStaticProps } from 'next';
import { useAppContext } from '../../context/AppContext';

interface PostProps {
  post: {
    field_body: string,
    field_description: string,
    field_posts_tags: string,
    nid: string,
    title: string,
    field_readingtime: string
  }
}

export default function PostTemplate({post}: PostProps) {
  console.log(post);
  return (
    <h2>test</h2>
  )
}

export const getStaticPaths: GetStaticPaths = async() => {
  return {
    paths: [],
    fallback: true
  }
}

export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async () => {
  const value = useAppContext();
  const postNid = value.postNid;
  const post = await fetch(`https://cms.jonasdev.com.br/api/posts/get/${postNid}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => response[0])

  return {
    props: {
      post
    },
    revalidate: 60 * 60 * 24 //24h
  }
}
```

Comment: You can't use `useAppContext` (a React hook) inside `getStaticProps` (not a React component). What does the `useAppContext` hook return exactly? What's the `value` you're trying to get?

Comment: Understood. I am trying to get the ID of a post, that I was able to store before on another component. I fought about using localstorge, but I believe I won't be able to use it on getStaticProps either to retrieve the stored data. The post ID is needed to use on the API call.

Comment: Keep in mind that `getStaticProps` runs on the server at build time. It doesn't have access to any request or client-side data. Move the logic to the client if you need to retrieve that kind of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I could not find a way to use context inside of getStaticProps I changed how I handle the get request - now I'm no longer using the post id (postNid) but the slug (e.g /using-multiple-deploy-keys) to query the full data of the post. Since I'm no longer using context I was able to use getStaticProps to fetch the data.

For reference, the commits here (https://github.com/jonas-gerosa361/jonasdev/commits/main) on March 10th cover this change in detail.